# How to turn on/off Portrait Orientation Lock iPhone in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I've used my code to set the screen's brightness.

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

Can I use the code to enable and disable the screen orientation lock of my iPhone?

Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• Set the shouldAutorotate to False

```
 override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
 }
```

• Specify the orientation.

```
override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations:UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

P.S : You can do this for in a screen in **your** app, not on the system (iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

3rd party applications can't manipulate all system settings or other app settings as it is likely going to cause security breaches. It's called sandboxing. Every app has it's own "Sandbox" or to put it simply, a prison where it cannot access/manipulate system settings or other app settings, which make the Apple devices really secure.

Although you can manipulate the orientation of you application using

```
override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: I understood that I cannot interfere with the system, Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to update device orientation:

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIDeviceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

Or

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```